# Is there a generic event that is fired when a browser tab or window closes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, is there a generic event that is fired when a browser tab or window is closed?

If so, is there cross-browser support?

Comment: Do you mean you want to differentiate between those three events?

Comment: If it's just the one 'leaving/closing' event - see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only *semi-consistent* event you have is [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

```
Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.
```

Sample:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('closing');

    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Comment: Very good info. Just 1 step further, at this beforeunload event, i want to collect info from the browser local cache storage, use HTTP post to send the info to another app for auto saving. Do you see any issues ?

Comment: try this between `e.preventDefault();` and `e.returnValue = '';`